# How do I fix: ImportError: cannot import name 'PandaRequest'?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

This is my first time using a jupyter notebook.

I was trying to import the panda module:

```
import panda as pd
```

but I get the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/panda/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from request import PandaRequest

ImportError: cannot import name 'PandaRequest'
```

How to fix this?

Edit: I wanted to use pandas but typed panda instead. :'D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have installed and imported the `panda` module, which is the a Python implementation of the Panda REST interface and which has incomplete dependencies.

What you probably want to do is install `pandas` (with the final **s**) and import that.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem and come up with the following solutions:

```
import pandas as pd
```

instead of

```
import panda as pd
```

It is called `pandas`.

Answer (score -2):

Execute `pip install panda`. You don't have the Panda module.

Edit: My mistake, it looks like there's an error within the Panda module itself. Does it rely on PandaRequest?

Comment: I do have the panda module.

Comment: Yea, just saw that. Edited my post.

Comment: Well, it seems like that, since in the "__init__.py " of the package it's used

Comment: They're multiple Panda python modules. I'm assuming you're trying to use http://pandas.pydata.org/?

Comment: I just realized my mistake, I was trying to use panda instead of pandas...